# How to give gradient color to topBar wix's react-native-navigation V2

Tags: android, react-native, linear-gradients, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I am using Wix's react-native-navigation V2. I want to give gradient color to the topBar. I have installed react-native-linear-gradient successfully. But I am not getting how to give gradient color to topBar.

Following is the code of pushing the screen into the stack.

```
Navigation.push('mainStack', {
      component: {
        name: 'SignIn',
        options: {
          topBar: {
            visible: true,
            animate: false,
            //hideOnScroll: true,
            //buttonColor: 'white',
            drawBehind: false,
            title: {
              text: 'Sign In',
              fontSize: 18,
              //color: 'white',
              fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
              alignment: 'center'
            },
            backButton: {
              // icon: require('icon.png'),
              id: 'backButton',
              visible: true,
              //color: 'white'
            },
            background: {
              color: '#1abc9c'
            }
          },
          sideMenu: {
            left: {
              enabled: false
            }
          },
          animations: {
            push: { // It works! Push with animation from right to left
              content: {
                x: {
                  from: 1000,
                  to: 0,
                  duration: 100,
                },
                alpha: {
                  from: 1,
                  to: 1,
                  duration: 100,
                }
              }
            },
            pop: { // It works! Pop with animation from left to right
              content: {
                x: {
                  from: 0,
                  to: 1000,
                  duration: 50,
                },
                alpha: {
                  from: 1,
                  to: 1,
                  duration: 50,
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

I tried to give a gradient color in options like below

```
background: {
              color: <LinearGradient colors={['#a8ff78', '#78ffd6']} style={styles.container} />
            }
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that works, I've always used that library wrapping the component that I want to have the gradient color, like below

```
<LinearGradient
      colors={["#34495E", "#2e4154", "#485b6e"]}
      start={{x: 0.0, y: 0}}
      end={{x: 0.60, y: 0}}
>
  <View>
    {...}
  </View>
</LinearGradient>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want gradient color in topBar

Answer (score 0):

Render `<LinearGradient colors={['#a8ff78', '#78ffd6']} style={styles.container} />` in a React Component and register it using `Navigation.registerComponent()` and then use it as follows

```js
topBar: {
  background: {
    component: {
      name: "" // The name of the registered component
    }
  }
}
```

The only problem is that the component will not render in the unsafe area.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting the meaning of the last line can you please explain.

Comment: The component won't render in the status bar area on phones with notches

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain why